# VBA add cells using defined variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add 2 cell values separated by a defined variable, but I cannot use the `"RC"` offsets based on that variable correct in `VBA`.
More specifically, I compute a variable I call `LR`. 
I am on cell `D2` and It's value should be: `[cell C(LR+1)]^2 + [cell C(2LR+1)]^2`.

I tried something like `...= R[& LR+1 &]C[-1]^2 + R[& 2*LR+1 &]C[-1]^2` without any luck.

Any idea how to use that relevant distance in an excel macro?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code? it will help to understand your issue

Comment: This title is completely useless. Please [edit] your question with a better title. Protip: imagine what you would type in Google if you were looking for a solution to that problem. Also please read [mcve] and edit your question so that it's on-topic. Right now, ...it's unanswerable.

Comment: ...for some values of *unanswerable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable needs to be outside the quotes and concatenated with `&`

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "= R[" & LR+1 & "]C[-1]^2 + R[" & 2*LR+1 & "]C[-1]^2"
```

Comment: you got that from the description above.. you must be a mind reader :). If that's the answer.. I bow to your mind reading capabilities :)

Comment: I think the question was pretty straight forward....you are supposed to help others, not only criticize.

Comment: @Thomas didn't mean to "criticize". you don't seem to have the slightest idea of how many shitty questions get asked here every day. Take your time to ask clear questions of undisputable quality, and you'll love this place. Spend little or no efforts on your questions and you'll get answers *if you're lucky* (like now), and by collecting downvotes and closed posts *the system itself* will end up blocking your account from asking new questions. It's not about "criticizing", it's about making this site enjoyable for everyone. "Critics" mean to *improve* your post, not bitch at it.

Comment: @Thomas, question is not straight forward. it is far from it. ... you asked to add two cell values. that is an arithmetic operation that is performed on numbers ... example: 3+4   .... "separated by defined variable" makes no sense .... you made no effort to explain what it is that you want